# How to convert a array containing object string to regular key object pair?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, underscore.js

I am trying to convert my uri to object value, as a success level i converted and splited in to array values with colon. But i am not able to onvert those to regular object. any one suggest me a good way. I am suing underscorejs with me.

here is my code :

```
var ar = ["id:1231", "currency:GBP"];

var outPut = _.map(ar, function(item){
    return '{' + item + '}';
})

console.log(outPut); //consoles as ["{id:1231}", "{currency:GBP}"]
```

how can i get result like this:

```
var object = {id:1231, currency:GBP}
```

is underscore has any in build method for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you could go about this, and Underscore offers helpers for them.

One way would be to use `_.reduce` to incrementally add key/value pairs to an initially empty "result" object:

```
var obj = _.reduce(ar, function(result, item) {
    var keyAndValue = item.split(":");
    result[keyAndValue[0]] = keyAndValue[1];
    return result;
}, {});
```

Note that you can do [the same without Underscore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) unless you have to support IE 8 or earlier.

Comment: works but not able to get proper result. here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/vaeRN/4/ can you update here.

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Sorry, I got the order of `result` and `item` wrong. Edited the answer to reflect the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Without any third part library:

```
var output = {} ;
var ar = ["id:1231", "currency:GBP"];
ar.forEach(function (item) {
    var values = item.split(':') ;
    output[values[0]] = values[1] ;
}) ;
```

Output `console.log(output)`:

```
Object {id: "1231", currency: "GBP"}
```

Comment: Please, don't use for...in with regular array

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon why so?

Comment: @Sprottenwels: If any properties are blindly set on `Array.prototype` (e.g. to install some kind of polyfill) then you would be iterating over those as well. You don't want that.

Comment: @Jon
Thank you. 
So it would be fine if i would do a `hasOwnProperty` check?

Comment: @Sprottenwels much slower, bad practice. You just shouldn't use it for arrays.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I didn't know about that, thx for your comment. I updated my answer. @Sprottenwels if you're already using `underscore.js` you should use @Jon answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version using jQuery:

```
var newObj = {};
$.each( ar, function( i, v ) {
    var kv = v.split( ":" );
    newObj[ kv[0] ] = kv[ 1 ];
 });
 // newObj = {id:"1231", currency:"GBP"}
```